# Memory leak in TFJS application even after disposing unused tensors

Tags: javascript, memory, tensorflow.js

### Issue

I am running a multi stage object detection network on Tensorflow JS. The first part is a seperate network detecting objects and then cutting them out of the main input image. Those cutout images can vary in size and are fed directly to the second network which performs another detection.
My application works perfectly fine but runs out of memory after some time. I figured out that the reason for the memory growth are the cutout tensors which still allocate memory even after disposing them.

### System

- @tensorflow/tfjs v.3.7.0
- Microsoft Edge v.91.0.864.59

### Code

```
while(running) {
   tf.engine().startScope()
   ...
   for(cutout count...)
      ...
      const cropped_image = input_tensor.slice([ymin, xmin], crop_size)
      const cropped_image_expanded = tf.expandDims(cropped_image, 0);
      const pred = await this.props.models.ssd_2nd_stage.executeAsync(cropped_image_expanded);

      tf.dispose(cropped_image);
      tf.dispose(cropped_image_expanded);
      ...
   }
   ...
   console.log(tf.memory())

   tf.engine().endScope()
   tf.engine().disposeVariables()
}
```

### Log

At the beginning `tf.memory()` shows this:

```
{unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 136710800, numBytesInGPUAllocated: 563751816, numBytesInGPUFree: 427041016, numTensors: 1517, …}
```

And after a while...

```
{unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 136710800, numBytesInGPUAllocated: 615142084, numBytesInGPUFree: 478431284, numTensors: 1517, …}
```

You can clearly see that TFJS does not free the previous GPU allocations which results in a OOM error after some time.

**Is there something that I'm missing?**

Answer (score 2):

I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple days now trying to figure out the memory leak in my tfjs-node prediction server. I have tried every single possible combination of dispose, startScope, endScope, etc. There just doesn't seem to be a solution and I'm starting to think tfjs-node itself is inherently flawed. Even worse for me is that tf.memory() provides me "unreliable" memory usage stats, and doesn't even provide a reason why, which it is supposed to. Strongly considering switching over to python for my server since the node bindings seem to be so shaky.

Comment: any updates on that?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow.js does not release WebGL textures cache. They keep accumulating until the GPU runs out of memory. Set the WEBGL_DELETE_TEXTURE_THRESHOLD flag to force the TFJS to release WebGL textures.

For example:

```
// Prevents OutOfMemory - forces TFJS to clear WebGL textures when reaching 256Mb
tf.env().set("WEBGL_DELETE_TEXTURE_THRESHOLD", 256000000);
```

Note that the optimal threshold value may vary depending on the model being used. To determine the appropriate value, you can log the GPU memory consumption after each inference:

```
console.log(`numBytesInGPUAllocated: ${tf.memory().numBytesInGPUAllocated}`);
```

You can then set the threshold to the amount logged after 2 probes, as the memory consumption increases with each probe.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got my memory clean with tfjs. A couple of things were needed.

1. Dispose tensors with either of those ways

```
myTensor.dispose()
```

or

```
tf.dispose(myTensor)
```

or

```
tf.tidy(() => { // my tensor operations
```

2. ALSO you need to manually dispose your model. It is not automatically disposed, also not if you decide to use `tf.tidy()`.

To do so, simply use the correct method

```
model.dispose()
```

Afterwards I got my tensorflow clean again

```
    console.log("numTensors (outside tidy): " + tf.memory().numTensors);
// prints: numTensors (outside tidy): 0
```